# Fresco - Support multiple OKHttp Clients

Tags: android, okhttp, fresco, imagedownload

My android app supports multiple user logins. 
I user Dagger2 to maintain the `UserScope` dependencies which get created and destroyed as user switch happens. 
One of these dependencies is an `OkHttpClient` for every user, with its own authentication/cookies.

I am looking to use `Fresco` for my app, but I am not able to find a way where I can switch the `OKHttpClient` at runtime in Fresco, since the initialization only happens once for it. 
From the documentation :

`OkHttpClient okHttpClient; //my per user session client
ImagePipelineConfig config = OkHttpImagePipelineConfigFactory
    .newBuilder(context, okHttpClient)
    .build();
Fresco.initialize(context, config);`

Any ideas to achieve this multi user scenario with Fresco ?

Comment: "its own authentication/cookies" Can you pop/modify these when you need to? Alternatively, can you swap Fresco clients when you need to (a new Fresco client with a new OkHttpClient)? You could probably prefill the new Fresco client with the old one's memory cache and such, too.

Comment: "Alternatively, can you swap Fresco clients when you need to (a new Fresco client with a new OkHttpClient)" This is what I was looking for, how can do this with Fresco. I thought he only initialization in the app is this call "Fresco.initialize(context, config)" how can I override it without killing the app ?

Comment: I'm not a Fresco user, so I'm not sure. I had a look at the API, and it looks like it doesn't give you control of the client. amazing. Probably file a feature request. Sorry.

Comment: You might be able to make an OkHttp interceptor that calls into another OkHttpClient instance altogether. It's weird but should just work.

Comment: Whoa, that's super cool. You could have one OkHttpClient that "delegates" to a swappable OkHttpClient in an Interceptor. When you want to swap users, swap out the OkHttpClient in the Interceptor. nice!

Comment: ... and @JesseWilson has a post on it now. haha! https://publicobject.com/2017/04/02/a-clever-flawed-okhttp-interceptor-hack/

Comment: Thanks guys, i just moved to using `Picasso` for my requirements, as it had a much cleaner interface with OKHttp to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a custom network fetcher that holds multiple OkHttpClients and change them when needed or create a new fetcher that holds multiple `OPkHttpNetworkFetcher`s.

Just use the original `OkHttpNetworkFetcher` code as a reference: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/imagepipeline-backends/imagepipeline-okhttp3/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/backends/okhttp3/OkHttpNetworkFetcher.java